# Как в python запустить паралельно две функции mainloop и socket

Tags: python, tkinter, сокет

мне надо запустить одновременно две функции window.mainloop (модуль tkinter) и функцию с сервером socket. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Питона с коробки есть модуль threading . Он позволяет выполнять функции паралелно.

вот шаблон:

```
from threading import *

t1 = Thread(target='функция 1')
t2 = Thread(target='функция 2')

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Повторюсь, они запускаются паралельно, то есть вторая не ждет окончае первой